# Chart.js doesn't animate on first load

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am using Chart.js to draw a Pie chart, yet it doesn't play its animations on the first time of loading - but it does if I reload it. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
function make_chart(ctx, data, type="pie"){
    var theChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: type,
        data: data,
        animate:{
            animateRotate: true,
            duration: 1000,
            animateScale: true,
            animationSteps: 15
        }

    })
    return theChart;
}

function example(ctx) {
    var data = {
    labels: [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "Yellow"
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [300, 50, 100],
            backgroundColor: [
                "#FF6384",
                "#36A2EB",
                "#FFCE56"
            ]

        }]  
    };
    return make_chart(ctx,data);
}

$(function() {
        example($("#chart"));
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Though it is run in $document.ready(), maybe not everything is initialized. I suggest to try to use setTimeout on the example function inside $document.ready().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe call your example function.

```
(function() {
        example($("#chart"));
})();
```

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean call it after the document.ready, or call it in the console seperately. Maybe my question wasn't clear enough - it runs in the document.ready, and creates a chart **without** animation. If I run it in the console, it creates a chart **with** animation

Comment: Do you mind putting it in a jsfiddle so I can run it?

Comment: Hmm, I need to be able to play around with it to help you :/

Comment: Idk why, jsfiddle can't handle it. I get an error in Chart.js when I try to do it in a fiddle :-(

Comment: I could put it in a github?

Comment: Put it somewhere and link it

Comment: I hate to break it to you but it animates on load for me haha

Comment: I'll try on a different machine

Answer (score 0):

just make canvas height according to your page visibility. it worked for me EX.
`<canvas id="pie_chart" height="78"></canvas>`